# Error 429 too many requests even when using proxies?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests, proxy

I have the following code, I tried to rotate user-agent and proxies for each search but I am still getting error 429. Is there a way to fix this? Is it my proxies? I have been steadily working on this code and it appears that it works except for the error 429 blocking it.

```
import openpyxl
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

def search_google(query):
    search_query = f"{query} facebook business profile"
    google_url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search_query}"

    ua = UserAgent()
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": ua.random
    }

    proxy = {
        "http": "http://elyaiwoq-rotate:flw5qf82idr6@p.webshare.io:80/",
        "https": "http://elyaiwoq-rotate:flw5qf82idr6@p.webshare.io:80/"
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(google_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
        time.sleep(10)  # Add a delay of 10 seconds between each search request

        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.content
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to retrieve Google search results. Status code: {response.status_code}")

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"An error occurred with the proxy {proxy['http']}: {e}")

def extract_facebook_profiles(html_content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

    profile_links = []

    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        href = link.get("href")
        if href and "facebook.com/" in href:
            profile_links.append(href)

    return profile_links

def read_excel_file(file_name):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = wb.active
    business_names = [cell.value for row in sheet.iter_rows() for cell in row]
    return business_names

def main():
    try:
        input_file_name = "business_names.xlsx"  # Replace with the name of your input Excel file
        output_file_name = "facebook_profiles.xlsx"  # Replace with the name of your output Excel file

        business_names = read_excel_file(input_file_name)
        all_results = []

        for business_name in business_names:
            print(f"Searching for Facebook business profile of '{business_name}' using the provided proxy...")
            try:
                search_results = search_google(business_name)
                profile_links = extract_facebook_profiles(search_results)

                if profile_links:
                    all_results.append([business_name, profile_links[0]])
                    print(f"Facebook profile found: {profile_links[0]}")
                else:
                    all_results.append([business_name, "Not found"])
                    print("Facebook profile not found.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred with the proxy: {e}")
            print("-" * 50)

        if all_results:
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            sheet = wb.active
            sheet.append(["Business Name", "Facebook Profile"])

            for result in all_results:
                sheet.append(result)

            wb.save(output_file_name)
            print(f"Search results saved to '{output_file_name}'.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Rotating user-agent, adding proxies rotating